# porting PIL python 2.x to pillow python3.10

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to port an old library from python 2.x which uses PIL to Python 3.10 with PILLOW. right now I am stuck the old library uses the fromstring command:

```
im = Image.fromstring( 'F', (im_width, im_height), rawdata,
                               'raw', decoder )
```

which gives me the following error:

```
File "C:\...\DM3lib.py", line 688, in image
    im = Image.fromstring( 'F', (im_width, im_height), rawdata,
  File "C:\...\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 108, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(f"module '{__name__}' has no attribute '{name}'")
AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'fromstring'
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to get the same functionality as the `fromstring` method?

Comment: This is what I found from Googling "pillow fromstring" (without the quotes): https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deprecations.html#image-fromstring-im-fromstring-and-im-tostring Basically, you're supposed to use `frombytes` instead, though you'd have to make sure that `rawdata` was a bytes object, not a string.

Comment: Since strings because Unicode in Python 3, I think you'll need to use [`Image.frombytes()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes) to do the same thing.

Comment: Note that you can convert a Python 3 string into `bytes` via `my_string.encode('latin1')`  because arbitrary binary strings are valid `latin1`.